# Wordpress Page not loading displays "Object Not Found" after migration from live to localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Wordpress Page not loading displays "Object Not Found" after migration from live to localhost server. I have configured the URLs to use localhost by replacing them in the database tables. I can well load the wordpress homepage and dashboard (admin panel) but when I try to load the pages it returns error.

Dashboard loading

[image]

Pages not loading

[image]

The .htaccess file seems completely fine.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /appe/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /appe/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I even tried adding these in `wp-config.php` (even though I already made URL changes in database)

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/appe/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/appe/');
```

But nothing seems to work. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. From dashboard I navigated to **Settings >> Permalinks** and saved the page once again by clicking on **Save Changes** button. Now the pages are loading fine!

Answer (score 0):

From dashboard I navigated to **Settings** >> **Permalinks** >> **Common Settings** >> **Post name** and saved the page once again by clicking on Save Changes button.

Ex: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXzyd.jpg

Comment: I already answered that an hour before you did.. What is the use of posting same answer again?